# A function to execute two functions but only one executes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried using a function to execute two functions when the page loads using *window.onload*, the issue I am having is that the function (myFunc) only executes the first function from the top (Func1) but not (Func2), the function looks like this

```
window.onload = function myFunc(){
    return Func1(); 
    return Func2(); 
}
```

So how can I execute both of them?

Comment: Maybe by putting one return statement at the last ?

Comment: I suggest using a linting tool or VS code editor so that you get compile time feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

make sure you define Functions before calling them, this is good practice

```js
//Arrow function and remove the return

const Func1 = () => {
  console.log('This is Func1');
}
const Func2 = () => {
  console.log('This is Func2');
}

window.onload = myFunc = () => {
  Func1();
  Func2();
}
```

Comment: It makes sense to remove return, I tried it but it is still the same, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

do not `return`  because after `return` goes out of function

```
window.onload = function myFunc(){
    Func1(); 
    Func2(); 
}
```

Comment: It is still the same, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the return keywords, and just run the function as is.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

```
window.onload = function() {
  Func1();
  Func2();
};
```

No need for return statements and naming the function. It should trigger both functions, if not please make sure the code change is reflected in the source by putting a breakpoint or adding a debugger; inside the function. Also check if both the function body are doing the same action so that you are concluding as second one not executing.

Answer (score 0):

js engine finishes the execution of function on return keyword.
so dont use return keyword to execute both functions